# Remove "recently opened apps" from Apps & notifications

Tags: applications, settings, recents-screen, 8.1-oreo

Using Android 8.1:

1. Tap **Settings**.
2. Tap **Apps & notifications**.

This displays a list of "Recently opened apps."

I would like to prevent the phone from storing, tracking, or otherwise remembering any app that has been opened. Ideally, without having to install yet another app. Rooting the phone is okay. Clearing the list is a work-around, but not a long-term solution.

How do you remove the "Recently opened apps" list from the **Apps & notifications** screen?